# Expanding knowledge of python / Next book and/or Topic to read/research

Tags: python, object-oriented

I have been programming python and web apps awhile now but never delved very deep into OOP. I use classes all the time but I am pretty sure i am not fully getting what I could get from OOP. So today I popped open Learn Python (mark lutz) which i had read awhile ago, flipped through the oop section in about 5 minutes and realized it contained nothing new. What would you suggest as a next step in becoming better at understand OOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried googling OOP????? It returns a pretty good result for WHAT OOP is in the first place :P "Classes" is just the tip of the iceberg. You need to know the 3 concepts -Inheritance,Encapsulation and Polymorphism theoretically before  getting started with implementation..in anyyy language,let alone Python.

Comment: Of course but a solid book recommend by people in the field or a specific topic (such as the ones you listed) goes a long way to  getting better books/google results. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I read this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136150314) awhile back when I thought about taking a Python gig. It was pretty good!

If you want a deeper understanding of OO in general there are a lot of resources on the web about [it](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=Object%20oriented%20&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=object%20oriented%20programming).